# Prism Xamarin Forms Tabbed Page Navigation

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a Xarmarin Forms application using Prism and Unity and am having trouble with navigation to a tabbed page.

I'm using the following versions: Prism.Forms v6.1.0-pre5 Prism.Unity.Forms v6.2.0-pre5 Xamarin.Forms v2.3.0.38-pre2

My tabbed page looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ServiceOrdersMobileApps.Views;assembly=ServiceOrdersMobileApps"
         x:Class="ServiceOrdersMobileApps.Views.ServiceOrderTabs">
 <NavigationPage Title="Summary">
  <x:Arguments>
    <local:ServiceOrderSummary />
  </x:Arguments>
 </NavigationPage>
 <NavigationPage Title="Complete">
  <x:Arguments>
    <local:ServiceOrderDetails />
    </x:Arguments>
  </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

I'm trying to navigate to the tabbed page with the Service Order Detail Page selected but when I navigate according to this [blog post](http://brianlagunas.com/prism-for-xamarin-forms-6-2-0-preview-3/).  It navigates past the tabbed page to a separate Service Order Detail Page

```
 var p = new NavigationParameters();
 p.Add("serviceorder", context);
 await _navigationService.NavigateAsync($"{nameof(ServiceOrderTabs)}/{nameof(ServiceOrderDetails)}",p);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the page wrapped in a generic NavigationPage that Prism doesn't know about.  You need to create a derived NavigationPage and register it for navigation. Then use that to wrap your COntentPages.  Then you can try navigating like "ServiceOrdersTabs/MyNavigationPage/ServiceOrdersDetails".

But even this may not work now that I think about it, because you'll have multiple instances of the same NavigationPage and Prism will use the first one it finds and use that.

For a work around, you'll have to create a different NavigationPage for each tab (ServiceOrderSummaryNavPage, ServiceOrdersDetailsNavPage, etc) to ensure that each Tab is unique.

By the way, from where are you navigating?

Comment: if i create ServiceOrdersDetailsNavPage thats implements NavigationPage, how can i create ServiceOrdersTabs children with my ServiceOrdersDetailsNavPage  because i can not calling my base constructor thats need a Page in the XAML. Thank you

Comment: Just add the pages to the TabbedPage in XAML like you normally would.